# Does the spring effect a moving ball?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring, speed

There is a  ball attached to spring which is streched out. The ball is held by a machine on the ground so it does not move, but when it is released it will quickly contract.

At the same time a football player kicks the ball straight inline with the spring, the machine releases the ball.

The kick made the ball move faster than the contraction speed of the spring. 
Does the spring have any effect on the speed of the ball?
Please explain.

Ask if its unclear.

Heres a drawing of the situation:)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Model 1: Kick is an impulse

A common approach for this problem would be to model the football player's kick as a sudden [impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_%28physics%29).  In this case, the kick happens in an instant and, immediately after the kick, the ball has a finite speed.  This speed does not depend on the spring.

So, *initially*, no, the spring has no effect: the speed of the ball is determined only by the kick's impulse.

As time progresses, the spring does has an effect.  So, after some time passes, then, yes, both the kick and the spring affect the speed.

### Model 2: High time resolution

The football player's kick does take some finite time, likely measured in milliseconds.  If we are interested in resolving what happens over that time scale, then, we will not model the kick as an impulse.  We would consider the kick's force as a function of time.  The spring will also provide a force as a function of time.  Both will affect the speed of the ball.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of this question is that you have three forces acting on the ball at the same time: the spring, the kick, and gravity.  The whole bit about the holding machine is just to get the kick and spring forces being applied at the same time.

These independent forces will have independent additive effects on the acceleration of the ball.  You can use Force/Mass = Acceleration to figure out what the acceleration of the ball is due to the spring and the kick individually, then add them together to figure out the total amount the ball will accelerate.

If these other forces and the acceleration of interest is perpendicular to the gravitational force (straight down to the center of the Earth) then the component contributed by gravity will be 0 and you don't have to worry about it.  I can't tell if you're modeling this as a 1D or 2D problem, though.

EDIT: Now that you have posted a diagram, I would also note that once the ball passes the point where the spring is at its natural length (0 spring force), the spring will start compressing and create a force in the opposite direction of motion.  The amount of momentum imparted in that first kick will determine how much the ball can compress the spring before its horizontal velocity crosses zero.

**In short, yes.**  The magnitude of the kicking force might be much larger than the magnitude of the spring force, in which case the error involved in not considering the spring force might be negligible and the benefits of a simpler model might be worth it.  You apparently aren't considering things like friction and air resistance, so you recognize some trade-off between model complexity and accuracy.  But, you can quantify how much difference the spring makes, and it's not precisely 0.